# waitForExpectations not working as expected in Swift

Tags: swift, unit-testing, tdd

Trying to write a unit test in Swift 4 for an already working method and having trouble getting the correct result. My current approach is:

```
    let expected = expectation(description: "Obtain access keys")
    let keys = sut.retrieveAccessKeys()
    //sleep(5)
    if keys != nil {
        expected.fulfill()
    } else {
        XCTFail("ERROR: Failed obtaining access keys")
    }

    waitForExpectations(timeout: 5) { error in
        let myError = error as? Error
        print("ERROR: \(String(describing: myError?.localizedDescription))")
    }
}
```

The `sut` makes a network call via a completion handler if the values don't exist within the keychain. The outputted error I get is:

```
Error: The operation couldn’t be completed. (com.apple.XCTestErrorDomain error 0.)
```

I've tried various ways including adding in `sleep(5)`. `sut. retrieveAccessKeys()` does work and the resulting `keys` contains an optional tuple.

Comment: You wrote that "sut makes a network call via completion handler" but you don't appear to be using a completion handler.  Ordinarily you would put your fulfill in the completion handler.  Also, how exactly are you verifying that sut.RetrieveAcessKeys is working?

Comment: I'm calling the method inside a viewController and running the app. The response from `retrieveAccessKeys()` is correct

Comment: Managed to solve the test by refactoring `sut.retrieveAccessKeys()` to be a closure with a completion handler. It looks as if the method was returning without waiting for it's internal method to finish.